# Как авторизовать пользователя в Kohana 3.3?

Tags: kohana, kohana-3

Есть сайт на Kohana 3.3, после регистрации пользователя,

```
Auth::instance('database')->login('login', 'password', true)
```

На отрез отказывается авторизовать пользователя, вот так:

```
Auth::instance()->force_login('login')
```

Все отлично, если попробовать сравнить хеш пароля:

```
Auth::instance()->password('login')
Auth::instance()->hash('password')
```

Все сходится.. В чем может быть проблема, куда копать?

config/auth.php

```
    return array(
    'driver'       => 'ORM',
    'hash_method'  => 'sha256',
    'hash_key'     => 12,
    'lifetime'     => 1209600,
    'session_type' => Session::$default,
    'session_key'  => 'auth_user',
);
```

config/session.php

```
    return array(
    'native' => array(
        'name' => 'session',
        'lifetime' => 43200,
    ),
    'cookie' => array(
        'name' => 'session',
        'encrypted' => FALSE,
        'lifetime' => 43200,
    ),
    'database' => array(
        'name' => 'session',
        'encrypted' => FALSE,
        'lifetime' => 1209600,
        'group' => 'default',
        'table' => 'user_sessions',
        'columns' => array(
            'session_id'  => 'session_id',
            'last_active' => 'last_active',
            'contents'    => 'contents'
        ),
        'gc' => 500,
    ),
);
```

bootstrap.php

```
........
    Cookie::$salt = '34hg6jfd74jh69c746nbe65hd565';

    if (PHP_SAPI != 'cli')
        Cookie::$domain = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

    Session::$default = 'database';
.......
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Забыл добавить роль 'login' для пользователей

Comment: Это решение вашего вопроса или уточняющий комментарий?